# Force unskipping paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs

I am using `OmegaT` for translating a huge amount of text, which I thereafter export to a text file format. However, due to the way `OmegaT` breaks text units up ("segmentation" they call it), I sometimes get results as the following:

```
This is the beginning of a line;
[this is a blank line]
and this is the end of the line.
```

which, when processed by `LaTeX`, get separated in paragraphs.

As I am able to use `LaTeX` code in the translated text, I was wondering if something like the following was possible:

```
This is the beginning of a line;\unskip
[this is a blank line]
\unskip and this is the end of the line.
```

which could get typeset continually. (Of course, `\unskip` didn't work for this here.)

This didn't work either:

```
This is the beginning of a line;%
[this is a blank line]
\unskip and this is the end of the line.
```

because there's a blank line after the `%`, of course.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you not control the blank line? (eg insert a `%`) If not I would not try to fix this in TeX, but just process the generated file with sed or perl to remove the blank lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I can't control that. A `Perl` script may work, but I was hoping there was something in `LaTeX` that could help me here.

Comment: It would help if you gave a complete example document to show the extent of the damage that needs to be repaired, it is possible to disable `\par` so make a blank line a no-op, but that will prevent latex doing anything, so you'd only want to do it in controlled local contexts, but hard to guess what your document looks like

Comment: It happens sparsely (once or twice per file), so a global solution will mess up my paragraphs.

Comment: it might be a good idea to explicitly mark the end of every "real" paragraph with `\par` in the source.  then it would be safe to remove all blank lines after the unruly software has polluted it.

Comment: How are *real* paragraph breaks marked? If they are marked by just a blank line, you're doomed.

Comment: Your requirements right now are basically impossible. How should TeX know which blank lines are meant to start new paragraphs and which aren't?

Comment: Well, I just need a command that does the following: if the *next* one is a blank line, ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need this one?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ignorenextpar{%
  \unskip\@ifnextchar\par{ \@gobble}{ }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is the beginning of a line;\ignorenextpar

and this is the end of the line.

The above blank line should not be ignored.\ignorenextpar
This should be normally spaced

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that copes with multiple blank lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ignorenextpar{%
  \@ifnextchar\par{\@gobblenextpar}{ }%
}
\newcommand\@gobblenextpar[1]{\ignorenextpar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is the beginning of a line;\ignorenextpar

and this is the end of the line.

This is the beginning of a line;\ignorenextpar


and this is the end of the line.

The above blank line should not be ignored.\ignorenextpar
This should be normally spaced

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\def\par{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\space\ignorespaces}
This is the beginning of a line;

and this is the end of the line.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't it be used once at at time (locally)? This will join all of my paragraphs...

Comment: @NVaughan as used above it only affects the one blank line in its scope can't be much more local than that can it? But your example was far from complete and didn't give any clue what your document looked like; if blank lines are to be ignored, how are you marking up paragraphs?

Comment: As I commented above, I just need a way of ignoring the next blank line.

Comment: @NVaughan so that's what the above does, you just need `{\def\par...` before the line and `}` after it.